# Unity Inventory System 'error CS1001: Identifier expected'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a simple script to create an inventory system, although I keep getting an 'Identifier Expected' error. I am trying to select the current item the script is attached to and add it to the inventory.

This is the error:

> Assets\Scripts\ItemObject.cs(10,25): error CS1001: Identifier expected

The tutorial I am following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGz3sbZkfkg

---

Here is the Inventory System:

InventorySystem.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InventorySystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Dictionary<InventoryItemData, InventoryItem> m_itemDictionary;
    public List<InventoryItem> inventory {get; private set;}

    private void Awake() {
        inventory = new List<InventoryItem>();
        m_itemDictionary = new Dictionary<InventoryItemData, InventoryItem>();
    }

    public void Add(InventoryItemData referenceData) {
        if(m_itemDictionary.TryGetValue(referenceData, out InventoryItem value)) {
            value.AddToStack();
        } else {
            InventoryItem newItem = new InventoryItem(referenceData);
            inventory.Add(newItem);
            m_itemDictionary.Add(referenceData, newItem);
        }
    }

    public void Remove(InventoryItemData referenceData) {
        if (m_itemDictionary.TryGetValue(referenceData, out InventoryItem value)) {
            value.RemoveFromStack();

            if(value.stackSize == 0) {
                inventory.Remove(value);
                m_itemDictionary.Remove(referenceData);
            }
        }
    }
}

 [Serializable]
public class InventoryItem {
    public InventoryItemData data {get; private set;}
    public int stackSize {get; private set;}

    public InventoryItem(InventoryItemData source) {
        data = source;
        AddToStack();
    }

    public void AddToStack() {
        stackSize++;
    }

    public void RemoveFromStack() {
        stackSize--;
    }
}
```

and here is the script that handles the item pickup:

ItemObject.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemObject : MonoBehaviour {
    public InventoryItemData referenceItem;

    public void OnHandlePickupItem() {
        InventorySystem.this.Add(referenceItem);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Any help would me much appreciated :)

Comment: What is the **complete, exact** error message you're getting, and what line is indicated as containing the problem? You have that information on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen from here. You're asking us for help to solve a problem, and it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for us to do so by providing all of the relevant information. Please [edit] your post to add that information.

Comment: Apologies for that, I have updated the post to include the Full Error and the file names. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not refer to `InventorySystem` with `InventorySystem.this.Add(referenceItem)` in `ItemObject`.

Try following:

- Add the `InventorySystem` component to a GameObject in your Scene
- Tag this GameObject with a tag named `Inventory`
- With that you can find the InventorySystem by `GameObject.findByTag` (do this in the `Awake` method of `ItemObject`
- Use this object for adding/removing stuff from/to the InventorySystem

Comment: Thank you, this has been a big help!